# How to convert string (separated by commas)in to mutidimensional json array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

how to convert the string with commas from the database to multidimensional array with the names

I have one column name is working hours in that we stored the the data like 10:00 am,1:00 pm,2:00 pm,5:00 pm

my query is

```
$sqlbranch = "SELECT * FROM branch WHERE Bank_name='$bankname'";
        $resultbranch = mysql_query($sqlbranch);
        $branchArray = array();
        if (mysql_num_rows($resultbranch) > 0) {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbranch)) {
               $branchArray['branches'][] =array('Working Hours' =>$row['Working_hours']));
```

Now i want to convert the data into json array

I want json data looks like

```
"branches":[{"working_hours":[{"Morningtime":{"begin_time":"10:00", "end_time":"15:30"},
                        "eveningtime":{"begin_time":"16:00", "end_time":"18:30"}}]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `$hours = explode(',', $row['Working_hours'])`.

Next, `foreach ($hours as $hour) { $parts = explode(' ', $hour)` and `if ($parts[1] == 'pm' )` do another explode like `$digits = explode(':', $parts[0])` and add add `12` to `$digits[0]` else use the `$parts[0]` as time, and store it in a `$cHours` array.

After that create an array like `$branches = ['working_hours' => [ 'Morningtime' => ['begin_time' => $cHours[0], 'end_time' => $cHours[1]], 'eveningtime' => ['Morningtime' => ['begin_time' => $cHours[2], 'end_time' => $cHours[3]]`

And finally `json_encode($branches)` to get you json string.